"Galois theory" on graphs
Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph. For the sake of simplicity, let us assume $G$ is undirected and finite.
The automorphism group $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ contains all graph isomorphisms $\phi : G \rightarrow G$. This group acts on the set $V$ of vertices of the graph and encodes valuable information about the symmetry of $G$. Indeed, $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ also contains automorphisms that might preserve a certain clique of interest, or "zoom in" on certain subgraphs, or "fixed points" of other sorts.
In Galois theory, we are interested in the automorphism groups of field extensions. For example, if $L$ and $F$ are fields, then we are interested in the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(L/F)$ on the roots of polynomials defined within $F[x]$ that might have roots in $L$, how the roots permute. Indeed, if $L/F$ is a Galois extension, we have a one-to-one correspondence between subfields of $L/F$ and subgroups of its automorphism group, and this is related to the splitting properties of polynomials with coefficients in $F$, etc…
I’m wondering if there is anything to the idea of perhaps representing (or considering) graphs by “polynomials” and trying to find “extension graphs” (graph coverings seem analogous to this idea). The intrinsic computational/combinatorial difficulties of graphs would seem to cause issues, but I am still curious if people have come up with something.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dessin_d%27enfant might be relevant.

There is actually an exact analogue of Galois theory in this context, given by the theory of covering spaces in topology. Covering space theory defines a topological version of a (separable) field extension called a covering space, and specialized to graphs, the covering spaces of a graph are always graphs and can be defined purely combinatorially - these are covering graphs. One can give a definition of when a covering is Galois and compute Galois groups, and there's a Galois correspondence.
All of this is covered in various introductions to algebraic topology (which will sadly introduce much more machinery than what you need just to study the special case of graphs, which is in principle self-contained and purely combinatorial). Hatcher's discussion of covering spaces, for example, has some nice pictures of coverings of graphs, including infinite graphs.
As an example, suppose $X = C_n$ is the cycle graph on $n$ vertices, $n \ge 3$. Then the (connected, finite) covering graphs of $X$ are exactly the cycle graphs on $kn$ vertices, $k \ge 1$; the covering maps $C_{kn} \to C_n$ are defined by "wrapping around," and have Galois group the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_k$, which controls which covers are intermediate between which other covers. This is very similar to what the theory of extensions of a finite field looks like, and the similarity can be described in terms of a similarity between the fundamental group of $C_n$ (which is $\mathbb{Z}$) and the absolute Galois group of a finite field (which is the profinite integers).

Thank you! I will try to construct some computations of Galois groups with the theory of covering spaces myself. I suspected some correspondence here, given you can treat graphs as topological spaces -- I just hadn't made the connection. My account is too new to upvote, but I will accept this as an answer.

I am not aware of any established reference for the combinatorics of homotopy theory on graphs, but I have had good experiences with Stillwell’s “Classical Topology and Combinatorial Group Theory.” He develops the combinatorics of covering space theory for graphs from the bottom up, as this is what was done classically before it was known that some manifolds cannot be triangulated (also, it is delightfully written).

This correspondence is referred to,  in the film "A beautiful mind".

@While One could argue that "graph minor theory" comes close to being the homotopy theory on graph.
